# how to get value from a window I window.show();

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

I am writing a simple app which whena buttton is clicked a command is binded and i am doing

```
 {...
newEvent.ExecuteTargets += exacuteNewEvent;
    }

    void exacuteNewEvent(string message)
    {
        Window1 w = new Window1();
        w.ShowDialog();

    }
```

my problem is how the w invoke my main window to know it has a new nassage 
should i insert to delegate in w a method of window he should invoke ?
is there another way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an reference to the current form and use that to call functions on it.

```
class Form1 
{
    void Function() 
    {
        newEvent.ExecuteTargets += exacuteNewEvent;
    }

    void exacuteNewEvent(string message)
    {
        Window1 w = new Window1(this);
        w.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void ExecuteStuffInOtherWindow() 
    {
        // do something
    }
}

class Window1 
{
    Form _otherForm;

    public Window1(Form f) 
    {
        _otherForm = f;
        _otherForm.ExecuteStuffInOtherWindow(); // call code in other form
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand , what should ExecuteStuffWithWindow do ?

Comment: Oh, I see now, you don't want things to happen after your subwindow is closed but while it's open. In that case, i'll edit my answer, one minute :)